# Function variable value changes after definition

Tags: python

If I execute this code:

```
fs = []
for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
  def f():
    print(i)

  fs += [f]

for f in fs:
  f()
```

It prints:

```
4
4
4
4
```

I don't understand why. And how to make it print this:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Loop iterations don't create new scopes. So all the functions are closed over the same scope of `i`.

Answer (score 2):

to follow up @AirSquid answer,
if you execute the following code,
you will see the id(i) indicating the same address.

```py
fs = []

for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    def f():
        print(id(i))
        print(i)
    fs += [f]

for f in fs:
    f()
    print(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

when your for-loop over `i` completes, the last value of `i` that was assigned is 4.  So that is the value of `i` when you loop over `fs`

Going back to your `fs` variable...  You are just appending the originally empty list with 4 references to the (oddly placed) function, so it is just a list that has 4 things in it.  What they are is immaterial in this case.

So, in your last for-loop, it iterates 4 times (the length of `fs`) and each time it calls f() which internally assumes that `i` is a global variable and it prints the last value.

If you want to make it print `1, 2, 3, 4`, **delete everything** and write a better structured chunk of code and a function that takes a parameter `i` that you pass in or such.

Comment: Thanks @airsquid for your answer! I simplified as much as possible my example so it might be weird to have such a complicated code to just print 1, 2, 3, 4, but in my case, I really need to have a list containting X functions that each depend on a different value of i.

Answer (score 1):

hence its a pointer passed to function it need to be evaluated before being appended to list

my functional approach to this would be following:

```
fs = []
loop = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
  def f():
    string = f'print({i})'
    def f2():
        eval(string)
    return f2

  fs += [f()]

for _f in fs:
  _f()
```

output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

UPDATE:

you could also do this, makes more sense to me:

creating tuples of function and i instances then calling them with each other:

```
fs = []

for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    def f(j):
        print(j)

    fs += [(f, i)]

for i in fs:
    i[0](i[1])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is an interesting solution. The only thing is that it seems super hacky. Is there nothing better?

Comment: Created an update on it